# Supervisor silently fails to start/restart (nothing in logs)

Tags: supervisord

I have a fairly basic supervisor config:

```
[program:drape]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=python /home/ubuntu/drape/workers/drape.py
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
nocleanup=true
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/supervisord.out.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=32MB
stderr_logfile=/home/ubuntu/supervisord.err.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=32MB
startsecs=180
```

I don't think this config actually matters but posting anyway.  I'm using the stock supervisor global config.  I installed supervisor via standard `sudo apt-get -y install supervisor` ...and just to be sure:

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install supervisor
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
supervisor is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 69 not upgraded.
```

However, when I try to start supervisor, I get a completely silent failure:

```
ubuntu@...:~$ sudo service supervisor start
ubuntu@...:~$
```

There is nothing in the logs (My global config has `logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log`) and there is nothing in the "program logs" either (`logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log.<stream>.log`).

I have a similar provisioning process for other servers that run ruby daemons so to dig in a bit further, I even creating a very simple ruby script and made `chmod 777` the thing so there are no permission issues:

```
$ cat test.rb 
while 1
 puts "hi"
 sleep 1
end
$ ruby test.rb 
hi
hi
hi
...
```

My question is more of a ..."where should I look" question.  If supervisor isn't logging anything the only other place I can think to look of is the syslog which doesn't indicate anything crazy to me.

Answer (score 6):

Just a tip for others who may be struggling with this, **try running the daemon directly**

```
/usr/bin/supervisord
```

and you should actually **see the errors** that stop the supervisor from running. The supervisor init script is useless for hunting down the configuration errors.

Answer (score 2):

The silent failure is due to this line failing:

```
DAEMON=/usr/bin/supervisord
test -x $DAEMON || exit 0
```

in supervisor init script. It looks like for some reason supervisord was installed in `/usr/local/bin/` on this machine. Super annoying that nothing is printed...

Comment: That means that you have a local install of supervisor, and the init script has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @ch2500 I always install with `sudo apt-get -y install supervisor` so not sure why this time it's installed to a different location and also not sure why the default init script would not be configured to look in the directory the bins were installed in ....but looking into it